# Remove overlay on navigator push

Tags: flutter

I have an overlay image which I need to remove on GestureDetector tap, I called `overlayEntry.remove()` but it doesn't work outside of the method.

```
class _Home extends State<Home> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
// setting global
  OverlayEntry overlayEntry;
  OverlayState overlayState;
......
// calling method to show my overlay image when state init
  initState() {
    showOverlay(context);
......

//  method to show my overlay
  showOverlay(BuildContext context) async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));

    this.overlayState = Overlay.of(context);
    this.overlayEntry = OverlayEntry(
      maintainState: true,
        builder: (context) => Positioned(
              top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.50,
              left: 20.0,
              child: Image.asset(
                "assets/imgs/myimage.png",
                width: 120.0,
              ),
            ));

    this.overlayState.insert(this.overlayEntry);
  }
......

// somewhere else in the code on some element

    GestureDetector(
       onTap: () {
          this.overlayEntry.remove(); // This doesn't works
          Navigator.push(context,MyCustomRoute(builder: (context) => Page()),
        );
      },
```

As you see in my `GestureDetector` method I am calling `overlayEntry.remove()` but the overlay widget always stay there on all pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was calling `showOverlay` method second time in my code which was causing this issue.